# Interpolación de datos en unas coordenadas conocidas y separando en dos según las medidas

Tags: python, python-3.x

Estoy realizando un código en python que me tiene que leer todos los ficheros .xyz que tengo en una carpeta correspondientes a mediciones que he realizado, y mi misión es unir todos los ficheros, aplicarle varios filtros y obtener los datos separados en dos transectos (dos líneas de puntos según su coordenadas) y para dos casos de estudio que son según si la medición es LO o es HI (se puede ver según la columna a la que corresponde). A continuación muestro un ejemplo del dataframe inicial al unir todos los ficheros .xyz

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Además de la imagen, pongo la tabla como texto por si la tenéis que usar aunque me da error para que se pueda ver como una tabla:

> X Y   Z   0.30 HI 0.15 LO 0.50 HI 0.25 LO 0.80 HI 0.40 LO 1.10 HI 0.50
> LO    1.60 HI 0.80 LO 2.30 HI 1.20 LO
> 763831.44 4097444.34  4.56    176.94  0   208.62  0   226.08  0   251.9   0   282.44  0   299.86  0
> 763831.54 4097444.42  4.55    176.35  0   208.04  0   224.94  0   250.15  0   281.23  0   299.48  0
> 763831.64 4097444.49  4.54    175.02  0   206.29  0   222.61  0   247.61  0   279.77  0   298.94  0
> 763831.75 4097444.57  4.53    172.11  0   202.96  0   219.38  0   244.97  0   277.98  0   298.33  0
> 763831.85 4097444.65  4.52    168.97  0   199.57  0   216.69  0   243.23  0   276.74  0   298.07  0
> 763831.95 4097444.73  4.51    165.6   0   196.62  0   214.92  0   242.32  0   276.26  0   298.34  0
> 763832.05 4097444.8   4.5 162.74  0   194.65  0   213.95  0   241.81  0   276.08  0   298.52  0
> 763832.17 4097444.86  4.49    160.95  0   193.48  0   213.27  0   241.21  0   275.9   0   298.37  0
> 763832.28 4097444.92  4.48    159.29  0   192.17  0   212.18  0   240.39  0   275.77  0   297.7   0
> 763832.4  4097444.98  4.47    157.77  0   190.81  0   211.11  0   240.01  0   275.95  0   297.53  0
> 763832.52 4097445.04  4.46    156.14  0   189.3   0   210.3   0   239.85  0   275.84  0   297.54  0
> 763832.64 4097445.1   4.45    154.56  0   188.16  0   209.83  0   239.73  0   275.38  0   297.07  0
> 763832.75 4097445.16  4.44    153.99  0   188.06  0   209.96  0   239.78  0   275.08  0   296.64  0
> 763982.38 4097554.95  3.91    0   84.6    0   125.33  0   139.8   0   146.23  0   159.9   0   172.39
> 763982.27 4097554.88  3.92    0   84.5    0   125.23  0   139.67  0   146.07  0   159.79  0   172.34
> 763982.16 4097554.81  3.93    0   84.41   0   125.01  0   139.62  0   146.14  0   159.78  0   172.43
> 763982.06 4097554.74  3.94    0   84  0   124.68  0   139.47  0   146.17  0   159.76  0   172.6
> 763981.95 4097554.67  3.95    0   83.61   0   124.46  0   139.25  0   145.98  0   159.5   0   172.62
> 763981.85 4097554.6   3.95    0   83.36   0   124.28  0   139.18  0   145.95  0   159.68  0   173.05
> 763981.74 4097554.52  3.96    0   83.09   0   124.02  0   138.97  0   145.91  0   159.78  0   173.37
> 763981.63 4097554.45  3.97    0   83.02   0   123.82  0   138.65  0   145.73  0   159.72  0   173.42
> 763981.53 4097554.38  3.98    0   83.15   0   123.76  0   138.62  0   145.68  0   159.97  0   173.36
> 763981.42 4097554.31  3.99    0   83.1    0   123.68  0   138.73  0   145.84  0   160.18  0   173.64
> 763981.32 4097554.24  4   0   82.79   0   123.53  0   138.67  0   145.97  0   160.21  0   174.05
> 763981.19 4097554.14  4   0   82.63   0   123.5   0   138.78  0   146.13  0   160.51  0   174.26
> 763981.06 4097554.03  4   0   82.91   0   123.83  0   139.14  0   146.43  0   161.01  0   174.77
> 763980.93 4097553.92  4   0   83.22   0   124.12  0   139.21  0   146.36  0   161.01  0   174.87
> 763980.8  4097553.81  4   0   83.25   0   124.1   0   139.12  0   146.47  0   161.25  0   175.15
> 763980.67 4097553.71  4   0   83.29   0   123.96  0   139.15  0   146.76  0   161.54  0   175.85

Ya he realizado un código que me separa los datos según la X e Y de las dos líneas que tengo, así como he logrado separar los datos de las mediciones HI y LO.

El problema lo tengo a la hora de interpolar los datos para unas coordenadas conocidas. Os pongo el código que tengo para ver si podéis ayudarme a solucionar el error:

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import glob
from scipy.interpolate import Rbf

# Obtener una lista con todos los archivos .xyz en el directorio actual
archivos_xyz = glob.glob('*.xyz')

# Crear una lista vacía para almacenar los DataFrames
df_list = []

# Iterar sobre los archivos .xyz y leerlos en DataFrames
for archivo in archivos_xyz:
    # Saltar el archivo si su tamaño es menor a 6 filas (solo encabezado)
    if len(open(archivo).readlines()) < 6:
        continue
    df = pd.read_csv(archivo, sep='\s+', skiprows=[0,1,2,3,4,5,6], header=None) # modificar las columnas según corresponda
    df_list.append(df)

# Unir todos los DataFrames en uno solo
df= pd.concat(df_list, axis=0, ignore_index=True)

# Convertir todas las columnas a numéricas
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce')

# Leer los nombres de las columnas desde un archivo de Excel
column_names_file = 'NombreColumnas.xlsx'
column_names_df = pd.read_excel(column_names_file)

# Convertir la lista de nombres de columnas a una lista de Python
column_names = list(column_names_df['nombre_columnas'])

# Asignar los nombres de las columnas al DataFrame
df.columns = column_names

# Ordenar las columnas en el orden deseado
column_order = ['X', 'Y', 'Z', '0.30 HI', '0.15 LO', '0.50 HI', '0.25 LO', '0.80 HI', '0.40 LO', '1.10 HI', '0.50 LO', '1.60 HI', '0.80 LO', '2.30 HI', '1.20 LO']
df = df.reindex(columns=column_order)

# Reiniciar los índices del DataFrame
df.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)


##################################################################################################
#REALIZAMOS UN BUCLE PARA ELIMINAR LOS DATOS QUE NO SE ENCUENTREN DENTRO DE LA MEDIA NI LA DESVIACIÓN ESTANDAR
##################################################################################################
# Obtener las medias y desviaciones estándar para cada columna
# Calcular media y desviación estándar
# Definir las columnas a las que se les aplicará el filtro
filtro_columnas = ['0.30 HI', '0.15 LO', '0.50 HI', '0.25 LO', '0.80 HI', '0.40 LO', '1.10 HI', '0.50 LO', '1.60 HI', '0.80 LO', '2.30 HI', '1.20 LO']

# Definir el tamaño de la ventana para el cálculo de la media y desviación estándar móviles
ventana = 20

# Aplicar el filtro a cada columna
for col in filtro_columnas:
    # Calcular la media y desviación estándar móviles
    df[col+'_mean'] = df[col].rolling(window=ventana, center=True).mean()
    df[col+'_std'] = df[col].rolling(window=ventana, center=True).std()
    # Eliminar las filas que no cumplen la condición
    df_nuevo = df.dropna(subset=[col+'_mean', col+'_std'])

# Eliminar las columnas de las medias y desviaciones estándar móviles
df_nuevo = df_nuevo.drop(columns=[col+'_mean' for col in filtro_columnas] + [col+'_std' for col in filtro_columnas])

#Crear una nueva variable para almacenar los datos que cumplen la condición
df_nuevo = df.copy()
for col in filtro_columnas:
    # Calcular la media y desviación estándar móviles
    df_nuevo[col+'_mean'] = df[col].rolling(window=ventana, center=True).mean()
    df_nuevo[col+'_std'] = df[col].rolling(window=ventana, center=True).std()
    # Eliminar las filas que no cumplen la condición
    df_nuevo = df_nuevo.dropna(subset=[col+'_mean', col+'_std'])

# Eliminar las columnas de las medias y desviaciones estándar móviles
df_nuevo = df_nuevo.drop(columns=[col+'_mean' for col in filtro_columnas] + [col+'_std' for col in filtro_columnas])


##################################################################################################
#REALIZAMOS UN FILTRO DE LOS DATOS PARA QUE ESTÉN DENTRO DE LA ZONA DE ESTUDIO
##################################################################################################
#Transecto 1
# Cortar los datos según las coordenadas que estarían dentro del transecto 1
x_min = 763831.41245636
x_max = 764026.87390491
y_min = 4097443.6847421
y_max = 4097589.6279258
transecto1 = df_nuevo
transecto1 = transecto1.loc[(transecto1['X'] >= x_min) & (transecto1['X'] <= x_max) & (transecto1['Y'] >= y_min) & (transecto1['Y'] <= y_max)]


#Transecto 2
# Cortar los datos según las coordenadas
x_min = 763903.71816292
x_max = 764100.354425
y_min = 4097343.2652734
y_max = 4097486.7560664
transecto2 = df_nuevo
transecto2 = transecto2.loc[(transecto2['X'] >= x_min) & (transecto2['X'] <= x_max) & (transecto2['Y'] >= y_min) & (transecto2['Y'] <= y_max)]



##################################################################################################
#POR ÚLTIMO PROYECTAMOS LA MEDICIÓN DEL TRANSECTO AL TRANSECTO REAL PARA PODER REALIZAR LA INVERSIÓN
##################################################################################################
# Definir las coordenadas de los dos puntos por los que pasa la recta
T1 = transecto1

x1_1 =763828
y1_1 =4097442.88125
x2_1 =764014
y2_1 =4097574.02701


p1_1 = np.array([x1_1,y1_1])
p2_1 = np.array([x2_1,y2_1])

v = p2_1 - p1_1
v_norm = v / np.linalg.norm(v)


#########################################################################
T2 = transecto2

x1_2 =763902    
y1_2 =4097343.66174
x2_2 =764084    
y2_2 =4097474.11628


p1_2 = np.array([x1_2,y1_2])
p2_2 = np.array([x2_2,y2_2])

v2 = p2_2 - p1_2
v_norm2 = v2 / np.linalg.norm(v2)


def proyectar_punto(punto, p1, v_norm):
    # Calcular la proyección del punto en la recta conocida
    proyeccion = p1 + np.dot(punto - p1, v_norm) * v_norm
    # Calcular la dirección de la línea perpendicular
    perp_norm = np.array([-v_norm[1], v_norm[0]])
    # Encontrar el punto donde la proyección se cruza con la línea perpendicular
    interseccion = proyeccion + np.dot(punto - proyeccion, perp_norm) * perp_norm / np.dot(perp_norm, perp_norm)
    return interseccion

# Aplicar la función a cada fila del dataframe
coords_proyectadas = []
for i, row in T1.iterrows():
    punto = np.array([row['X'], row['Y']])
    coords_proyectadas.append(proyectar_punto(punto, p1_1, v_norm))
    
    
coords_proyectadas2 = []
for i, row in T2.iterrows():
    punto2 = np.array([row['X'], row['Y']])
    coords_proyectadas2.append(proyectar_punto(punto2, p1_2, v_norm2))    

# Crear un nuevo dataframe con las coordenadas proyectadas
df_proyectado = pd.DataFrame(coords_proyectadas, columns=['X_proyectado', 'Y_proyectado'])
df_proyectado2 = pd.DataFrame(coords_proyectadas2, columns=['X_proyectado', 'Y_proyectado'])

T1.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
T2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_proyectado.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)
df_proyectado2.reset_index(drop=True, inplace=True)

# Unir el nuevo dataframe con el original
T1 = pd.concat([df_proyectado,T1], axis=1)
T2 = pd.concat([df_proyectado2,T2], axis=1)

# Graficar los datos originales en azul
plt.scatter(T1['X'], T1['Y'], c=T1['0.80 LO'], cmap='cool')
plt.scatter(T2['X'], T2['Y'], c=T2['0.80 LO'], cmap='cool')

# Graficar los datos proyectados en rojo
plt.scatter(T1['X_proyectado'], T1['Y_proyectado'], c=T1['0.80 LO'], cmap='cool', alpha=0.5)
plt.scatter(T2['X_proyectado'], T2['Y_proyectado'], c=T2['0.80 LO'], cmap='cool', alpha=0.5)

# Graficar la recta conocida en negro
plt.plot([x1_1, x2_1], [y1_1, y2_1], 'k--')
plt.plot([x1_2, x2_2], [y1_2, y2_2], 'k--')

# Añadir un título y etiquetas de los ejes
plt.title('Datos proyectados en la recta conocida')
plt.xlabel('Coordenada X')
plt.ylabel('Coordenada Y')

# Añadir una barra de color para la variable de interés
plt.colorbar()

# Mostrar la gráfica
plt.show()


############################################################################################################
#CALCULO DE VARIOGRAMAS
############################################################################################################



############################################################################################################
#INTERPOLACIÓN DE LOS DATOS PARA EL TRANSECTO
############################################################################################################
# Cargar las coordenadas desde el archivo Excel
coordenadasT1 = pd.read_excel('CoordenadasT1.xlsx', usecols=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])
# Cargar las coordenadas desde el archivo Excel
coordenadasT2 = pd.read_excel('CoordenadasT2.xlsx', usecols=['X', 'Y', 'Z'])

# Eliminar filas con valores infinitos o NaN
T1 = T1[np.isfinite(T1).all(axis=1)]
T2 = T2[np.isfinite(T2).all(axis=1)]


# Crear el primer dataframe con las columnas HI
T1_hi = T1[['X', 'Y', 'Z'] + [col for col in T1.columns if 'HI' in col]]
# Crear el segundo dataframe con las columnas LO
T1_lo = T1[['X', 'Y', 'Z'] + [col for col in T1.columns if 'LO' in col]]
# Crear el primer dataframe con las columnas HI
T2_hi = T2[['X', 'Y', 'Z'] + [col for col in T2.columns if 'HI' in col]]
# Crear el segundo dataframe con las columnas LO
T2_lo = T2[['X', 'Y', 'Z'] + [col for col in T2.columns if 'LO' in col]]


# # Definir las columnas de datos de origen para la interpolación
columnas_datos = ['0.30 HI', '0.15 LO', '0.50 HI', '0.25 LO', '0.80 HI', '0.40 LO', '1.10 HI', '0.50 LO', '1.60 HI', '0.80 LO', '2.30 HI', '1.20 LO']
columnas_datos_HI = ['0.30 HI', '0.50 HI', '0.80 HI', '1.10 HI', '1.60 HI', '2.30 HI']
columnas_datos_LO = ['0.15 LO', '0.25 LO',  '0.40 LO',  '0.50 LO', '0.80 LO', '1.20 LO']

# # Definir el radio de búsqueda para la interpolación
radio_busqueda = 20

# # Inicializar los diccionarios para almacenar los resultados interpolados
resultados_T1_HI = {}
resultados_T1_LO = {}
resultados_T2_HI = {}
resultados_T2_LO = {}


# 1. Crear nuevos DataFrames para cada categoría
T1_HI_coords = T1_hi[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].join(T1[columnas_datos_HI])
T1_LO_coords = T1_lo[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].join(T1[columnas_datos_LO])
T2_HI_coords = T2_hi[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].join(T2[columnas_datos_HI])
T2_LO_coords = T2_lo[['X', 'Y', 'Z']].join(T2[columnas_datos_LO])



T1_HI_coords = T1_HI_coords[(T1_HI_coords.iloc[:, 3:] != 0).any(axis=1)]
T1_LO_coords = T1_LO_coords[(T1_LO_coords.iloc[:, 3:] != 0).any(axis=1)]
T2_HI_coords = T2_HI_coords[(T2_HI_coords.iloc[:, 3:] != 0).any(axis=1)]
T2_LO_coords = T2_LO_coords[(T2_LO_coords.iloc[:, 3:] != 0).any(axis=1)]

# 2. Seleccionar las filas del DataFrame original que corresponden a cada categoría
coordenadasT1_HI = T1_HI_coords[np.isfinite(T1_HI_coords).all(axis=1)]
coordenadasT1_LO = T1_LO_coords[np.isfinite(T1_LO_coords).all(axis=1)]
coordenadasT2_HI = T2_HI_coords[np.isfinite(T2_HI_coords).all(axis=1)]
coordenadasT2_LO = T2_LO_coords[np.isfinite(T2_LO_coords).all(axis=1)]


# Interpolación para coordenadasT1
for columna in columnas_datos_HI:
    # Generar la función de interpolación para la columna actual en coordenadasT1
    interpolacion_1HI = Rbf(coordenadasT1_HI['X'], coordenadasT1_HI['Y'], coordenadasT1_HI['Z'], coordenadasT1_HI[columna], function='linear', epsilon=radio_busqueda)
    # Evaluar la interpolación en las coordenadas de interés
    resultados_T1_HI[columna] = interpolacion_1HI(coordenadasT1['X'], coordenadasT1['Y'], coordenadasT1['Z'])

for columna in columnas_datos_LO:
    # Generar la función de interpolación para la columna actual en coordenadasT1
    interpolacion_1LO = Rbf(coordenadasT1_LO['X'], coordenadasT1_LO['Y'], coordenadasT1_LO['Z'], coordenadasT1_LO[columna], function='linear', epsilon=radio_busqueda)
    # Evaluar la interpolación en las coordenadas de interés
    resultados_T1_LO[columna] = interpolacion_1LO(coordenadasT1['X'], coordenadasT1['Y'], coordenadasT1['Z'])

# # Interpolación para coordenadasT2
# for columna in columnas_datos_HI:
#     # Generar la función de interpolación para la columna actual en coordenadasT2
#     interpolacion_2HI = Rbf(coordenadasT2['X'], coordenadasT2['Y'], coordenadasT2['Z'], coordenadasT2[columna], function='linear', epsilon=radio_busqueda)
#     # Evaluar la interpolación en las coordenadas de interés
#     resultados_T2_HI[columna] = interpolacion_2HI(coordenadasT2['X'], coordenadasT2['Y'], coordenadasT2['Z'])

# for columna in columnas_datos_LO:
#     # Generar la función de interpolación para la columna actual en coordenadasT2
#     interpolacion_2LO = Rbf(coordenadasT2['X'], coordenadasT2['Y'], coordenadasT2['Z'], coordenadasT2[columna], function='linear', epsilon=radio_busqueda)
#     # Evaluar la interpolación en las coordenadas de interés
#     resultados_T2_LO[columna] = interpolacion_2LO(coordenadasT2['X'], coordenadasT2['Y'], coordenadasT2['Z'])

# Convertir el diccionario de resultados en un dataframe y añadir las coordenadas
resultados_T1_HI = pd.DataFrame(resultados_T1_HI)
resultados_T1_HI['X'] = coordenadasT1_HI['X']
resultados_T1_HI['Y'] = coordenadasT1_HI['Y']
resultados_T1_HI['Z'] = coordenadasT1_HI['Z']
resultados_T1_HI = resultados_T1_HI.reindex(columns=column_order)

# resultados_T1_LO = pd.DataFrame(resultados_T1_LO)
# resultados_T1_LO['X'] = coordenadasT1_LO['X']
# resultados_T1_LO['Y'] = coordenadasT1_LO['Y']
# resultados_T1_LO['Z'] = coordenadasT1_LO['Z']
# resultados_T1_LO = resultados_T1_LO.reindex(columns=column_order)


# resultados_T2_HI = pd.DataFrame(resultados_T2_HI)
# resultados_T2_HI['X'] = coordenadasT2_HI['X']
# resultados_T2_HI['Y'] = coordenadasT2_HI['Y']
# resultados_T2_HI['Z'] = coordenadasT2_HI['Z']
# resultados_T2_HI = resultados_T2_HI.reindex(columns=column_order)


# resultados_T2_LO = pd.DataFrame(resultados_T2_LO)
# resultados_T2_LO['X'] = coordenadasT2_LO['X']
# resultados_T2_LO['Y'] = coordenadasT2_LO['Y']
# resultados_T2_LO['Z'] = coordenadasT2_LO['Z']
# resultados_T2_LO = resultados_T2_LO.reindex(columns=column_order)
```

Como os he comentado, necesito que el código pueda realizar la interpolación para los dos transectos conocidos y separando en HI y LO (en total deberían quedar 4 dataframes).
El error que me da es:

> raise LinAlgError('Matrix is singular.')
>
> LinAlgError: Matrix is singular.

¿Podríais ayudarme?
Muchas gracias

Comment: Buen día, las preguntas que buscan ayuda con la depuración deben incluir el comportamiento esperado, un problema específico o error, y el código más corto necesario para reproducirlo en la propia pregunta. Las preguntas sin un planteamiento claro del problema no son útiles para otros lectores. Véase: Cómo crear un [Ejemplo mínimo, completo y verificable](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). Por favor agrega algunas filas de tu `dataframe` como texto, el código mínimo para reproducir el problema y un ejemplo del resultado deseado.

Comment: He modificado el planteamiento, a ver si ahora se entiende mejor. Gracias!

Comment: No has puesto el error completo. No sabemos que linea es la que da el error. Pero el error está claro, te dice que la matriz és singular. Seguramente estes intentando una operacion que no tiene solucion en matrices singulares. Asegurate que la matriz que usas para la interpolacion no sea singular.

Comment: Hola Mario, tal vez te ayude ver [aquí](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44305456/why-am-i-getting-linalgerror-singular-matrix-from-grangercausalitytests?r=Saves_AllUserSaves).

Comment: Hola, gracias por vuestras respuestas. Como comento en el texto, el error me aparece al realizar la parte de interpolación. El tema de la matriz singular creo que puede estar debido a que con el código empleado no me elimina las filas que tengo con X e Y pero el resto de valores son 0. Esto lo he intentado aplicando algunos filtros pero no he obtenido éxito, por eso os paso el código que tengo sin dichos filtros. Por otra parte, si dejo el código tal y como os lo he puesto me lo realiza, pero al descomentar las últimas variables es cuando me dan los errores. No se si me explico bien.